# A proper solution to a WPF application using On Screen Keyboard

Tags: wpf, keyboard

I´ve been working for some time on a good OSK solution for my WPF apps, that are running on a tablet. But it´s hard working with the OSK.exe and tabtip.exe, because of several bugs, strange behaviour and no standardized solution to this ordinary problem.

What I (probably) need is a custom textbox control, which inherits from System.Windows.Controls.TextBox, and overrides some methods.

The simple requirements for this textbox should be:
1. When a user clicks in a textfield, the tabtip.exe (or alike) keyboard should pop up at the bottom of the screen (default).
2. If the keyboard pops up on top of the textbox, the contentframe should scroll so that the textbox is visible.
3. When the textbox loses focus, the keyboard should close automatically, except if the user clicks on another textbox.

This seems like pretty standard behaviour right? Well I´ve looked a long time for solutions (there is no standard microsoft way which is kind of weird), and as said I´ve tried making my own but with no luck. For example, sometimes when I try to kill the process, it fails. When I click the close button in the upperright corner on the keyboard, like 5-6-7 times, it closes. The behaviour from PC to tablet is not consistent. The ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(x); sometimes doesent work on a tablet, and so on.

So does any of you know a good solution to this common problem?

Comment: If you port your WPF to a Windows Store App (Metro), you get all this for free. What OS are you targetting?

Comment: @alski WinRT XAML is laughable when compared to WPF XAML.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. The keyboard hiding the focused field is very annoying. We are considering to open the tabtip from our application and writing the behaviour ourselves. Did you (or anyone else) find a better solution?

Comment: Invoking tabtip as an external process is painless, it will even read your InputScope properties and render itself accordingly.